# Passing a vector to constructor

Tags: c++

Iam new in C++  and iam trying to implement classes into my program. I have done similar program in java.  But iam struggling to implement classes in c++. I want to pass a vector with strings from main to a class  called Search.I can pass a vector either by value or reference. Iam using a vector * which means get vector address.This is what i was told. Iam not sure how i should refer to it. I am sure there are more mistakes in my code. Could please someone help me or explain me how to initialize vector in constructor and how to add a value  so I can use the vector in the menthod?? Iam using Visual Studio PRO 2010. Many thanks for replies.

Search.h

```
// pragma once  
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"  
#include <vector>   

class Search    
{  
public:  
Search();  
    Search(int dd, int mm, int year,vector<string>* dat);  
    vector<string> get_result ();  
    ~Search(void);  
private:     
int d;  
int m;  
int y;  
vector<string> data;   
};
```

Search.cpp

```
#include "Search.h"    
#include <vector>   
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"  
Search::Search()  
:d(1), m(1), y(2000), data(){} //data() is the vector but iam not sure if ihave set the value corectly 

Search::Search(int dd, int mm, int year,vector<string>*dat)    
:d(dd),m(mm),y(year), data(dat){}//no instance of constructor matches   the construcor list -- this is the error iam getting  
//iam trying to initiliaze the varibale data of type vector.But i dont know how to do it.  
Search::~Search(void)  
{    
}  
vector<string> Search::get_result ()  {// implementation where i need to use   the data stored in a vector  

}  

//main program  
   #include "std_lib_facilities.h"   
    #include <string>  
    #include <sstream>  
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include "Search.h"    
    #include <vector>    

   int main(){    
   int day, month, year;  //iam gonna ask user to input these
    day=20;  
    month=12;  
    year=2014;  

vector<string>flight_info;  
ifstream inputFile("flight.txt");

// test file open   
if (inputFile) {        
 string value;

  // read the elements in the file into a vector    
     while ( inputFile >> value ) {  
   flight_info.push_back(value);//this is the vector i want to pass to class   Search
       }

   }  

   Search search(day,month,year,flight_info)   
    //this where i want to create object of Search class but iam gettin error -no     instance of constructor matches the `enter     code here`construcor list.   

}
```

Comment: The 5th parameter of the Search constructor must be a pointer to vector, not a vector, like this: `Search search(day,month,year,&flight_info)`

Comment: Passing a pointer to X to a function is *not* the same as passing some X by reference. If you have been told to "pass by value or reference", then using a pointer is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This defines a vector:

```
vector<string>flight_info;
```

This defined a vector member variable:

```
vector<string> data;
```

This invoke a constructor by passing the vector to it:

```
Search search(day,month,year,flight_info)
```

But this constructor expects a *pointer* to a vector!

```
Search(int dd, int mm, int year,vector<string>* dat);
```

You don't need to pass any of the standard containers around by pointer (and you're probably doing something wrong if you find yourself trying to).

You can rewrite your constructor to be `Search(int dd, int mm, int year,vector<string> dat)` to resolve your error. You only need to change the prototype of your constructor, because `data(dat)` will already correctly construct the member vector.

Comment: The most efficient way would probably be `Search(int dd, int mm, int year, vector<string> dat) : /*...,*/ data(std::move(dat))`, rather than passing `dat` by reference.

Comment: Yeah, just spotted the copy of `dat`. I think introductory C++ might not be the best place to talk about move constructors, however. Ref parameters and mentions of efficiency have been removed.

Comment: Thanks it works now.. my question is when i need to actually use pointer & to a vector???

Comment: @userMilka I cannot think of any good reasons right now why you'd want to pass around raw pointers to vectors. Perhaps you might want to use a vector as the context in a C-style callback function. You could ask this as a new SO question, if you were interested enough.